# Can't find my zip codes in TIGER/tigris

Tags: r, tiger, sf, zip-codes

(This is my first attempt to use R, so I apologize for any stupidity. Also, please let me know if this is better posted in Stack Overflow.)

I'm trying to use the [Microsoft building footprint dataset](https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints) to make a map of buildings in my city (Cambridge, MA). I'm following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/etachov/a029c849c89ee3d4f7d59dda83f97ed2) as a guide. These lines of code are giving me problems:

```
options(tigris_class = "sf", tigris_use_cache = TRUE)
zctas_national <- zctas(cb = TRUE)

selected_zip <- zctas_national %>%
filter(ZCTA5CE10 %in% c(02139))
```

When I try to `print(selected_zip)`, I get nothing back. Or rather, I get a table that looks like this:

```
[1] ZCTA5CE10  AFFGEOID10 GEOID10    ALAND10    AWATER10   geometry
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If I replace 02139 with 85308 (the zip from the gist), everything is fine:

```
  ZCTA5CE10     AFFGEOID10 GEOID10  ALAND10 AWATER10
1     85308 8600000US85308   85308 44254346   872904
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a guess but...

```
   filter(ZCTA5CE10 %in% c(02139))
```

will treat that 02139 as a number, drop the leading zero, and look for "2139", which doesn't exist. Try making it into a *character* value:

```
   filter(ZCTA5CE10 %in% c("02139"))
```

If this is your first use of R, go through some R tutorials that only use the *base* R packages (and *dont* use all the "tidyverse" packages) to get a sound understanding of the fundamentals like this. Walk before you run!

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I thought it may have been a problem with the leading zero. Not sure why I never tried making it a string. :)